# A similar Somos sequence problem prove $A_{2n}B_{n+3}$ is integer sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I have read some interesting with [Somos sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SomosSequence.html),Recently I met a similar question：

> For a fixed positive integer $k$, there are two sequences $A_n$ and $B_n$.
>   They are defined inductively, by the following recurrences.
>   $$A_1 = k,A_2 = k,A_{n+2} = A_{n}A_{n+1}$$
>   $$B_1 = 1,B_2 = k, B_{n+2} = \frac{B^3_{n+1}+1}{B_{n}}$$
>   Prove that for all positive integers $n$, $A_{2n}B_{n+3}$ is an integer.

I try to Solve this problem,following is my some works.

since
$$A_{n+2}=A_{n}A_{n+1}\Longrightarrow \ln{A_{n+2}}=\ln{A_{n}}+\ln{A_{n+1}}$$
so we have
$$A_{n}=k^{f_{n}}$$
where $f_{n}$ be the Fibonacci sequece,which satisfies $f_{1}=f_{2}=1,f_{n}=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$

for $B_{n}$ It is difficult to handle, even for a general term

**If we choose to use mathematical induction**

(1):if  $n=1$ since
$$B_{3}=k^3+1,\Longrightarrow B_{4}=\dfrac{(k^3+1)^3+1}{k}$$
so we have
$$A_{2}B_{4}=(k^3+1)^3+1$$ is integer

if $n=2$,we have
$$B_{5}=\dfrac{B^3_{4}+1}{B_{4}}=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{(k^3+1)^3+1}{k}\right)^3+1}{k^3+1}=\dfrac{((k^3+1)^3+1)^3+k^3}{(k^3+1)k^3}$$
and $A_{3}=k^2,A_{4}=k^3$,so we have
$$A_{4}B_{5}=\dfrac{((k^3+1)^3+1)^3+k^3}{k^3+1}=\dfrac{(k^3+1)^9+3(k^3+1)^6+3(k^3+1)^3+(k^3+1)}{k^3+1}
=(k^3+1)^8+3(k^3+1)^5+3(k^3+1)^2+1\in N^{+}$$
Now Assmue that $A_{2n}B_{n+3}(n\le k)$ is integer,or $n^{f_{n}}B_{n+3}(n\le k)$ is integrthen consider $$A_{2k+2}B_{k+4}=(k+1)^{f_{k+1}}\cdot\dfrac{B^3_{k+3}+1}{B_{k+2}}$$
Now the problem is equlivant to  prove
$$\dfrac{(B^3_{k+3}+1)(k+1)^{f_{k+1}}}{B_{k+2}}\in N^{+}~~~?$$

Comment: Your last sentence makes sense only in the case when $B_{k+2}, B_{k+3}$ are integers, but in general this is not true. Moreover, $A_{2k+2} = k^{f_{2k+2}} \neq (k+1)^{f_{k+1}}$.

Comment: @Crostul,Thanks,I have edit it

Comment: Isn't it "Somos sequence"?

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_n = A_{2n} B_{n+3}$.

I will prove that $C_n \in \Bbb Z[K]$ forall $n \ge -1$ and their dominant coefficient is $1$, and its degree is greater than $A_{2n}$'s degree.

Since $A_{2n+4}A_{2n} = A_{2n+2}^3$,
we get the recurrence relation

$C_n C_{n+2} = A_{2n}A_{2n+4}B_n B_{n+2} = A_{2n+2}^3(B_{n+1}^3+1) = C_{n+1}^3 + A_{2n+2}^3$.

---

I will proceed by induction.
For now I suppose that $n \ge 1, C_{n-2},\ldots,C_{n+1} \in \Bbb Z[K]$ (with dominant coefficient $1$ etc), and $C_{n-1}$ and $C_n$ have no common root.

---

First I want to show that $C_{n+2} \in \Bbb Q[K]$.
To do this I need to show that $C_{n+1}^3 + A_{2n+2}^3 \equiv 0 \pmod {C_n}$ .

I want to multiply this by $C_{n-1}^3$ to use the recurrence relation, which is why I need $C_{n-1}$ "coprime" with $C_n$.

If $c_n \in \Bbb Z$ is the resultant of $C_{n-1}$ and $C_n$, then you have a Bézout relation $U_nC_{n-1} + V_nC_n = c_n$ where $U_n,V_n \in \Bbb Z[K]$ ($c_n \neq 0$ because $C_n$ and $C_{n-1}$ have no common root)

Now, I will show that $c_n^3C_{n+2} \in \Bbb Z[K]$.

$c_n^3C_nC_{n+2} = (U_n C_{n-1} + V_n C_n)^3(C_{n+1}^3 + A_{2n+2}^3) \equiv U_n^3(C_{n-1}^3C_{n+1}^3 + C_{n-1}^3 A_{2n+2}^3) \pmod {C_n}$

But, $C_{n-1}^3C_{n+1}^3  = (C_n^3+A_{2n}^3)^3 \equiv A_{2n}^9 = A_{2n-2}^3 A_{2n+2}^3$.

Factoring out $U_n^3 A_{2n+2}^3$, it is enough to have $A_{2n-2}^3 + C_{n-1}^3 \equiv 0$

But $A_{2n-2}^3 + C_{n-1}^3 = C_nC_{n-2} \equiv 0$.

This proves that $c_n^3 C_n C_{n+2}$ is $C_n$ times a large polynomial expression in $U_n,V_n,C_{n-2},C_{n-1},C_n$, or also, that $C_{n+2} = \frac 1 {c_n^3} P(U_n,V_n,C_{n-2},C_{n-1},C_n)$ where $P$ has integer coefficients.

---

To show that $C_{n+2}$ is in fact in $\Bbb Z[K]$, we use $C_{n+2} = (C_{n+1}^3 + A_{2n+2}^3) / C_n$ and look at its Taylor development at infinity.

Since both $(C_{n+1}^3 + A_{2n+2}^3)$ and $C_n$ have integer coefficients, and $C_n$'s dominant coefficient is $1$, we get by doing the division, that $C_{n+2} \in \Bbb Z[K][[1/K]]$.

Now since $C_{n+2} \in \Bbb Q[K]$, it has to be in their intersection, which is $\Bbb Z[K]$.

---

Finally, if $C_{n+1}$ and $C_n$ have a common root $k \in \Bbb C$, then $k$ is also a root of $A_{2n}$, so it has to be $0$ (because $A_{2n}$ is a power of $K$). Then if $n \ge 2$, this implies that $C_{n-1}$ also has $0$ as a root (because $A_{2n-2}(0)= 0$).

As for the degrees, $C_n$ and $A_{2n}$ follow the same linear recurrence on the degree except that $C_n$ has a big headstart ($\deg(C_0) = 3, \deg(C_1) = 9$ and $\deg(A_0) = 0, \deg(A_2) = 1$)

---

To initialize the recurrence you only need to check that $C_{-1},C_0,C_1,C_2$ are all polynomials and that the pairs $(C_0,C_1)$ and $(C_1,C_2)$ don't have a common root.

### ---

The part about showing by induction that $C_n$ is coprime with $A_{2n}$ can be translated in terms of a recurrence for the Bézout relation :

Suppose you have some rational fraction $U_n,V_n$ such that $U_n C_n + V_n A_{2n} = 1$

Taking the cube of this, we get, modulo $A_{2n}$, 
$1 = U_n^3 C_n^3 = U_n^3 (C_{n-1}C_{n+1} - A_{2n}) = U_n^3 C_{n-1} C_{n+1}$
And so $1 = U C_{n+1} + V A_{2n}$ where $U = U_n^3 C_{n-1}$ and $V$ a big polynomial expression in $U_n,V_n,C_n,A_{2n}$.

Taking the cube again, we get, modulo $C_{n+1}$,
$1 = V^3 A_{2n}^3 = V^3 A_{2n-2} A_{2n+2}$, and so we get a new Bézout relation
$1 = U_{n+1} C_{n+1} + V_{n+1} A_{2n+2}$ where $U$ and $V$ are huge polynomial expressions in $U_n,V_n,C_{n-1},C_n,A_{2n-2},A_{2n}$.

And whenever we have such an expression we do the same as above where we pick $c_n = 1$ in order to get an expression for $C_{n+2}$ in terms of $U_n,V_n,\ldots$. And so for every choice of $U_1,V_1$, this gives a *polynomial* recurrence to compute the sequences $(U_n,V_n,C_n,A_{2n},A_{2n+1})$ in terms of the initial values $(C_{-1},C_0,C_1,C_2,U_1,V_1,A_0,A_1)$.

Now those initial values are all in $\Bbb Z[K]$, except $U_1$ and $V_1$.

For example if you choose $U_1 = 0$ and $V_1 = 1/A_2 = 1/K$, you get a recurrence that proves that $C_n \in \Bbb Z[K, 1/K]$.
If you choose $U_1 = 1/2$ and $V_1 = -(K^6+3K^3+3)/2$ (this relation comes from the resultant of $C_1$ and $A_2$ being $2$), you get a recurrence that proves that $C_n \in \Bbb Z[K, 1/2]$.

(I still don't know if there is a "trivial" proof, a purely polynomial recursion for $C_n$ where initial values are all in $\Bbb Z[K]$)

Answer (score 1):

$ \text{Because } A_{n} = k^{f_{n}} \Rightarrow \text{If } $
$ \{ B_{n} = k^{-\alpha_{n}} P(k) \quad\&\quad \alpha_{n+3} \le f_{2n} \} \Rightarrow A_{2n}B_{n+3} = k^{f_{2n}-\alpha_{n+3}} P(k) \in N^{+} $
$ \text{Where } \alpha_{n} \in N^{+} \,,  \space\space P(k) \space \text{is a polynomial in} \space k $
$ \text{Although above condition is enough, we will prove a stronger condition:} $
$ \{ B_{n} = k^{-\alpha_{n}} P(k^{3}) \quad\&\quad \alpha_{n+3} = f_{2n} \} \Rightarrow k^{f_{2n}} B_{n+3} = P(k^{3}) \in N^{+} $
$ \text{Which is more visiable after calculating few $ B_{n} $ items:} $
$ k^{0} B_{3} = 1 + k^{3} $
$ k^{1} B_{4} = 2 + 3 k^{3} + 3 k^{6} + k^{9} $
$ k^{3} B_{5} = 8 + 29 k^{3} + 61 k^{6} + 86 k^{9} + 85 k^{12} + 59 k^{15} + 28 k^{18} + 8 k^{21} + k^{24} $
$ k^{8} B_{6} = 256 + 2400 k^{3} + 11964 k^{6} + 41233 k^{9} + \space ... \space + 210 k^{57} + 21 k^{60} + k^{63} $
$ k^{21} B_{7} = 2097152 + 51380224 k^{3} + 644743168 k^{6} + \space ... \space + 1485 k^{159} + 55 k^{162} + k^{165} $
$  $
$ \underline{\text{(1). The Combination Sequence:}} $
$ B_{1} = 1 \,, \space B_{2} = k \,, \space B_{3} = k^{3} + 1 \color{red}{= B} \space\space \{ \in N^{+} \} $
$ \text{By cubing, substitution, and rearranging; we get the following combination sequence:} $
$ B_{4} B_{2} = B^{3} + 1 \quad \small \Rightarrow (B^{3} + 1)^{3} = B^{3}_{4} B^{3}_{2} = (B_{5} B_{3} - 1) B^{3}_{2} = B_{5} B_{3} B^{3}_{2} - B^{3}_{2} \Rightarrow $
$ B_{5} B_{3} B^{3}_{2} = (B^{3} + 1)^{3} + B^{3}_{2} \quad \small \Rightarrow ((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + B^{3}_{2})^{3} = B^{3}_{5} B^{3}_{3} B^{9}_{2} = (B_{6} B_{4} - 1) B^{3}_{3} B^{9}_{2} \Rightarrow $
$ B_{6} B_{4} B^{3}_{3} B^{9}_{2} = ((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + B^{3}_{2})^{3} + B^{3}_{3} B^{9}_{2} \quad \small \Rightarrow $
$ B_{7} B_{5} B^{3}_{4} B^{9}_{3} B^{27}_{2} = (((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + B^{3}_{2})^{3} + B^{3}_{3} B^{9}_{2})^{3} + B^{3}_{4} B^{9}_{3} B^{27}_{2} \quad \small \Rightarrow \space ... \space \Rightarrow $
$ B_{n+3} B^{3^{0}}_{n+1} B^{3^{1}}_{n} B^{3^{2}}_{n-1} ... B^{3^{n-2}}_{3} B^{3^{n-1}}_{2} = ( ... (((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + B^{3}_{2})^{3} + B^{3}_{3} B^{9}_{2})^{3} + ... )^{3} + B^{3^{1}}_{n} ... B^{3^{n-1}}_{2} $
$ \text{Where all combinations } \in N^{+} \text{, because it had been constructed without division} $
$  $
$ \underline{\text{(2). The Combination Factors:}} $
$ B_{3} = B \Rightarrow k^{0} B_{3} = B = k^{3} +1 = P(B) \in N^{+} $
$ B_{4} B_{2} = B^{3} + 1 \Rightarrow k^{1} B_{4} = B^{3} + 1 = (k^{3} +1)^{3} + 1 = P(B) \in N^{+} $
$ B_{5} B_{3} B^{3}_{2} = (B^{3} + 1)^{3} + B^{3}_{2} \Rightarrow $
$ \qquad \small k^{3} B_{5} \cdot B = (B^{3} + 1)^{3} + k^{3} = \left[ (B^{3} + 1)^{3} \color{red}{- 1} \right] + \left[ k^{3} \color{red}{+ 1} \right] = \left[ (B^{3} + 1)^{3} - 1 \right] + \left[ B \right] $
$ \qquad \small \text{RHS is divisible by B, because after expanding the fixed coefficients will canceled} $
$ \qquad k^{3} B_{5} = \frac{(B^{3} + 1)^{3} + (B - 1)}{B} = P(B) \in N^{+} $
$ B_{6} B_{4} B^{3}_{3} B^{9}_{2} = B_{6} (B^{3}_{3} + 1) B^{3}_{3} B^{\color{red}{8}}_{2} = ((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + B^{3}_{2}) + B^{3}_{3} B^{9}_{2} \space\space \Rightarrow $
$ \qquad k^{8} B_{6} \cdot (B^{3} + 1) B^{3} = ((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + k^{3})^{3} + B^{3} k^{9} $
$ \qquad \small = ( \left[ (B^{3} + 1)^{3} \color{red}{- 1} \right] + \left[ k^{3} \color{red}{+ 1} \right] )^{3} + B^{3} k^{9} = ( \left[ (B^{3} + 1)^{3} - 1 \right] + \left[ B \right] )^{3} + B^{3} k^{9} \quad \{ \div B^{3} \} $
$ \qquad \small = \left[ ((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + k^{3})^{3} \color{red}{- k^{9}} \right] + \left[ B^{3} k^{9} \color{red}{+ k^{9}} \right] = \left[ ((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + k^{3})^{3} - k^{9} \right] + \left[ (B^{3} + 1) k^{9} \right] \quad \{ \div (B^{3} + 1) \} $
$ \qquad k^{8} B_{6} = \frac{((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + (B - 1))^{3} + (B^{3} + 1) (B - 1)^{3}}{(B^{3} + 1) B^{3}} = P(B) \in N^{+} $
$ B_{7} B_{5} B^{3}_{4} B^{9}_{3} B^{27}_{2} = B_{7} (B^{3}_{4} + 1) B^{3}_{4} B^{\color{red}{8}}_{3} B^{27}_{2} = B_{7} ((B^{3}_{3} + 1)^{3} + B^{3}_{2}) (B^{3}_{3} + 1)^{3} B^{8}_{3} B^{\color{red}{21}}_{2} \space\space \Rightarrow $
$ \qquad \small k^{21} B_{7} \cdot ((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + k^{3}) (B^{3} + 1)^{3} B^{8} = (((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + k^{3})^{3} + B^{3} k^{9})^{3} + (B^{3} + 1)^{3} B^{9} k^{24} $
$ \qquad \small = (( \left[ (B^{3} + 1)^{3} \color{red}{- 1} \right] + \left[ k^{3} \color{red}{+ 1} \right] )^{3} + B^{3} k^{9})^{3} + (B^{3} + 1)^{3} B^{9} k^{24} \quad \{ \div B^{9} \} $
$ \qquad \small = ( \left[ ((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + k^{3})^{3} \color{red}{- k^{9}} \right] + \left[ B^{3} k^{9} \color{red}{+ k^{9}} \right])^{3} + (B^{3} + 1)^{3} B^{9} k^{24} \quad \{ \div (B^{3} + 1)^{3} \} $
$ \qquad \small = \left[ (((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + k^{3})^{3} + B^{3} k^{9})^{3} \color{red}{- B^{9} k^{27}} \right] + \left[ (B^{3} + 1)^{3} B^{9} k^{24} \color{red}{+ B^{9} k^{27}} \right] \quad \{ \div ((B^{3} + 1)^{3} + k^{3}) \} $
$ \qquad k^{21} B_{7} = P(B) \in N^{+} \quad \text{ ... etc.} $
$ \text{Thus, by adding and subtracting the cube of the last terms,} $
$ \text{the factors are eliminated, and leaving: } k^{\alpha_{n}} B_{n} = P(B) \in N^{+} $
$  $
$ \underline{\text{(3). The Combination Power:}} $
$ \text{Let } P_{n}(k) \text{ and } Q_{n}(k) \text{ polynomials in } k \text{. According to combination sequence and factors:} $
$ k^{\alpha_{3}} B_{3} P_{3} = Q_{3} = B_{3} = k^{0} B_{3} \small \quad \{ \alpha_{3} = 0 \} $
$ k^{\alpha_{4}} B_{4} P_{4} = Q_{4} = B_{4} B_{2} = k^{1} B_{4} \small \quad \{ \alpha_{4} = 1 \} $
$ k^{\alpha_{5}} B_{5} P_{5} = Q_{5} = B_{5} (B_{3}) (B^{3}_{2}) = B_{5} \left( \frac{Q_{3}}{k^{\alpha_{3}} P_{3}} \right) \left( k^{\alpha_{4}} P_{4} \right)^{3} = k^{3} B_{5} \frac{Q_{3} P^{3}_{4}}{P_{3}} \small \quad \{ \alpha_{5} = 3 \times 1 - 0 = 3 \} $
$ k^{\alpha_{6}} B_{6} P_{6} = Q_{6} = B_{6} (B_{4}) (B^{3}_{3} B^{9}_{2}) = B_{6} \left( \frac{Q_{4}}{k^{\alpha_{4}} P_{4}} \right) \left( k^{\alpha_{5}} P_{5} \right)^{3} = k^{8} B_{6} \frac{Q_{4} P^{3}_{5}}{P_{4}} \small \quad \{ \alpha_{6} = 3 \times 3 - 1 = 8 \} $
$ k^{\alpha_{7}} B_{7} P_{7} = Q_{7} = B_{7} (B_{5}) (B^{3}_{4} B^{9}_{3} B^{27}_{2}) = B_{7} \left( \frac{Q_{5}}{k^{\alpha_{5}} P_{5}} \right) \left( k^{\alpha_{6}} P_{6} \right)^{3} = k^{21} B_{7} \frac{Q_{5} P^{3}_{6}}{P_{5}} \small \quad \{ 3 \times 8 - 3 = 21 \} $
$ \text{Giving the sequence: } \{ \alpha_{3} = 0 \,, \alpha_{4} = 1 \,, \alpha_{n+3} = 3 \alpha_{n+2} - \alpha_{n+1} \} = \{ 0 \,, 1 \,, 3 \,, 8 \,, 21 \,, 55 \,, \space ... \} $
$ \text{And the question: prove } \quad \alpha_{n+3} = f_{2n} \quad \colon \space n \ge 0 $
$ \text{Where: } \{ f_{0} = \alpha_{0} = 0 \,,\space f_{1} = \alpha_{1} = 1 \,,\space f_{n} = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2} \quad\&\quad \alpha_{n} = 3 \alpha_{n-1} - \alpha_{n-2} \} $
$ \alpha_{n+3} = 3 \alpha_{n+2} - \alpha_{n+1} \Rightarrow \quad \alpha_{n+3} = f_{2n} \iff f_{2n} = 3 f_{2(n-1)} - f_{2(n-2)} = 3 f_{2n-2} - f_{2n-4} $
$ f_{2n} = 1 f_{2n-1} + f_{2n-2} \qquad \{ f_{2n-1} = f_{2n-2} + f_{2n-3} \} \Rightarrow $
$ f_{2n} = 2 f_{2n-2} + f_{2n-3} \qquad \{ f_{2n-3} = f_{2n-2} - f_{2n-4} \} \Rightarrow $
$ f_{2n} = 3 f_{2n-2} - f_{2n-4} \qquad \Rightarrow \alpha_{n+3} = f_{2n} $

Answer (score 0):

Considering the sequence (for $n \ge 2$):
$$
A_{2(n-1)} B_{(n-1)+3}, \space A_{2n} B_{n+3}, \space A_{2(n+1)} B_{(n+1)+3} \space \rightarrow \space A_{2n-2} B_{n+2}, \space A_{2n} B_{n+3}, \space A_{2n+2} B_{n+4}
$$
According to definitions, we have:
$$
{ A_{2n+3} = A_{2n+2} A_{2n+1} = (A_{2n+1} A_{2n}) A_{2n+1} = A^2_{2n+1} A_{2n} = A^3_{2n} A^2_{2n-1} \brace A_{2n+3} = A_{2n+2} A_{2n+1} = A_{2n+2} (A_{2n} A_{2n-1}) = A_{2n+2} A^2_{2n-1} A_{2n-2} }
$$
$$
\Rightarrow A^3_{2n} = A_{2n+2} A_{2n-2}
$$
And,
$$
B_{n+4} = \frac{B^3_{n+3}+1}{B_{n+2}} \Rightarrow B^3_{n+3}+1 = B_{n+4} B_{n+2}
$$
Thus,
$$
A^3_{2n} (B^3_{n+3}+1) = (A_{2n+2} A_{2n-2}) (B_{n+4} B_{n+2})
$$
$$
\Rightarrow (A_{2n} B_{n+3})^3 + A^3_{2n} = (A_{2n+2} B_{n+4}) (A_{2n-2} B_{n+2})
$$
By checking the first two terms: $(A_{2n-2} B_{n+2} = A_2 B_4 \in N^{+}), \space (A_{2n} B_{n+3} = A_4 B_5 \in N^{+})$ and because all $A_k \in N^{+}$

$ \Rightarrow $ Every next term in the sequence is an integer.
$$
(A_{2n} B_{n+3})^3 + A^3_{2n} = (A_{2n+2} B_{n+4}) (A_{2n-2} B_{n+2}) \Rightarrow (Int)^3 + (Int)^3 = (A_{2n+2} B_{n+4}) \cdot (Int)
$$
$$
\Rightarrow A_{2n+2} B_{n+4} \in N^{+}
$$

Comment: The chain is as weak as its weakest link. After a good start, why do you think that from $(Int)^3 + (Int)^3 = (A_{2n+2} B_{n+4}) \cdot (Int)$ it follows that: $A_{2n+2} B_{n+4} = (Int)$ ?